# CUPS - Printing process stuck in "Connecting to printer."

Tags: cups

I am trying to set up a Raspberry Pi running on Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) as printer server. My printer is a Brother-MFC-L2710DN.

I have connected the printer and the computer with an ethernet cable. I have installed CUPS on the computer. I added the printer in CUPS.

Whenever I try to print a test page, the printing job gets added to the queue, but it never gets printed. The process is stuck in the status "Connecting to printer."

```
root@raspi:/home/jonathan# lpstat -t
scheduler is running
no system default destination
device for Brother_MFC-L2710DN_series: dnssd://Brother%20MFC-L2710DN%20series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-b4220052ea11
Brother_MFC-L2710DN_series accepting requests since Tue May 17 18:06:53 2022
printer Brother_MFC-L2710DN_series now printing Brother_MFC-L2710DN_series-20.  enabled since Tue May 17 18:06:53 2022
    Connecting to printer.
Brother_MFC-L2710DN_series-20 jonathan          1024   Tue May 17 18:06:53 2022
```

```
root@raspi:/home/jonathan# lpinfo -v
direct vnc:/
direct hp
file cups-brf:/
network beh
network lpd
network ipps
network socket
network http
network https
network ipp
direct hpfax
network dnssd://Brother%20MFC-L2710DN%20series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-b4220052ea11
network ipp://Brother%20MFC-L2710DN%20series._ipp._tcp.local/
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you did not install a specific printer drivers... They are mandatory for Brother's printers. Just to register in CUPS is not enough.

Look here for the drivers:
https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcl2710dn_eu